# module-shared-catalog cant install

Tags: magento2

In Magento2.2. I saw it in Extension Manager and then install..but can't.. someone faced this problem?

Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies.
Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

> Installation request for magento/module-shared-catalog 100.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-shared-catalog[100.0.0].
>   - magento/module-shared-catalog 100.0.0 requires magento/module-advanced-checkout 100.2.* -> no matching package found.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this? I couldn't update to 2.2 so I removed the sample modules (php bin/magento sampledata:remove). This worked a treat, but when reinstalling the sample modules (like you have), I got the same error.

Comment: With u same..so don’t know how to do ..

Answer (score 0):

What I did is **not included** the `magento/module-shared-catalog` on Extensions Manager Page and it works for me.